# What would be the "board" and "scratching away" here?

Tags: meaning-in-context

Here is a text of a book describing what Darwin would have done in his study, if we were watching him. What would be the "board" and "scratching away" here?

> At first, we see him sitting in his easy chair, scratching away eagerly upon a board resting on his knee. We expect him to look engrossed and satisfied, and for a while he does.

Would this be a board for a notepad and he is erasing what he has written? Or a wooden board for engraving?
I find it vague for me. This is an excerpt from Martin Brasier's book Darwin's lost world. I'm not a native.

Comment: I take it to be a board for supporting notebook or paper (as distinct from writing at a desk). A quill pen or early steel nib would have made a scratching sound on the paper.

Comment: @KateBunting Thank you. I found a good idea in your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**writing board** (n.)

> A board used to provide a firm surface for supporting papers, a
> notebook, etc., while writing; (occasionally) such a board forming
> part of a piece of furniture. Also: any of various types of board used
> for writing on directly.
>
> 1854   R. M. Kettle *Lewell Pastures* I. xv. 206   An old bureau,
> which..was furnished with a sort of sliding desk or writing-board,
> which could be drawn in and out at pleasure. (OED)
>
> 2015   K. Bolick *Spinster* vii. 209   On a typical morning
> she'd..lean her writing board across her knees, and work steadily
> until noon, filling sheaves of foolscap.

From the above we see that *writing boards* fall into three categories: boards that are used as a support surface and placed, for example, across the lap; boards that are part of a piece of furniture; and boards that can be written on directly (e.g., slate, whiteboard).

Some small 19th-century *writing desks* are sometimes called *writing boards* by auction houses:

[image]

Regarding "scratching away"—Fountain pens may become scratchy with use. They can be made to write smoothly by cleaning/soaking the nib or using a [smoothing/buff stick](https://www.indy-pen-dance.com/Fountain-Pen-Nib-Buff-Stick.html), which appears to be similar to a fine emery board.